# Backup batch eating first part of some names

Tags: batch-file, recursion, backup, filenames, move

I have made a backup batch file which scans a folder for files and moves them over 0byte copies in a premade 0byte directory clone.
It works fine for the most part of finding and moving 2000+ files and rebuilding a tree from them but I have found a few names are having their first half eaten and this causes multiple files to be moved over to a singular 0byte file.

```
    @ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "SDPath=MiSTer_SD"
set "backupPath=_ROOT"

for /R "%SDPath%" %%G in (*.*) do (
    if %%~zG EQU 0 (
        for /R %backupPath% %%g in ("*%%~nxG") do (
            MOVE "%%g" "%%G" )
    )
)
```

The output looks like this when things are going wrong

```
    D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD>(if 0 EQU 0 (for /R "_ROOT" %g in ("*Beyblade (USA).chd") do (MOVE "%g" "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\MiSTer_SD\Beyblade\Beyblade (USA).chd"  ) ) )

D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD>(MOVE "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\_ROOT\Beyblade (USA).chd" "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\MiSTer_SD\Beyblade\Beyblade (USA).chd"  )
        1 file(s) moved.

D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD>(if 0 EQU 0 (for /R "_ROOT" %g in ("*Blade (USA).chd") do (MOVE "%g" "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\MiSTer_SD\Blade\Blade (USA).chd"  ) ) )

D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD>(MOVE "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\_ROOT\Blade (USA).chd" "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\MiSTer_SD\Blade\Blade (USA).chd"  )
        1 file(s) moved.

D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD>(MOVE "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\_ROOT\Bushido Blade (USA).chd" "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\MiSTer_SD\Blade\Blade (USA).chd"  )
        1 file(s) moved.

D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD>(if 0 EQU 0 (for /R "_ROOT" %g in ("*Boxing (USA).chd") do (MOVE "%g" "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\MiSTer_SD\Boxing\Boxing (USA).chd"  ) ) )

D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD>(MOVE "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\_ROOT\Boxing (USA).chd" "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\MiSTer_SD\Boxing\Boxing (USA).chd"  )
        1 file(s) moved.

D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD>(MOVE "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\_ROOT\HBO Boxing (USA).chd" "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\MiSTer_SD\Boxing\Boxing (USA).chd"  )
        1 file(s) moved.
```

I know its to do with how i have written ("*%%~nxG") but im unsure of how to fix it

I cant for the life of me figure out why its grouping a few like name source files together and overwriting a single destination file with them?
Any help is greatly appreciated, or even a different approach to the whole backup idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for /R %backupPath% %%g in ("*%%~nxG") do (
```

Says : For all files that end with `%%~nxG`

`Blade (USA).chd` and `Bushido Blade (USA).chd` both match this criterion, so both will be moved.

Perhaps if you were to remove the `*` it would accomplish what you want.

Comment: That was my first thought, and it does fix the file names, but then the output filename is double quoted and wont process. removing the quotes from (%%~nxG) makes the batch fail to load also.
example

 `MOVE "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\_ROOT\"Blade (USA).chd"" "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\MiSTer_SD\Blade\Blade (USA).chd"`

Comment: `MOVE "%%~g" "%%G"` should fix that problem.

Comment: I gave it a go but the output didnt change, what does adding the ~  do?
`D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD>(if 0 EQU 0 (for /R "_ROOT" %g in ("Blade (USA).chd") do (MOVE "%~g" "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\MiSTer_SD\Blade\Blade (USA).chd"  ) ) )

D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD>(MOVE "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\_ROOT\"Blade (USA).chd"" "D:\_WORK\TOOLS\MiSTer_REBUILD\MiSTer_SD\Blade\Blade (USA).chd"  )
The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Comment: Hmm - it seems `for /r` includes the quotes around the filename. `%~g` should strip quotes, BUT only does so if the first and last character are quotes. You appear to be using `for /r` because you're not sure exactly where the file is... Try using `MOVE "%%~dpg%%~nxG" "%%G"`, taking the drive and path from `%%g` (where the file is located) and the name and extension from `%%G`, which would obviously match the name and extension found by `for /r`. I'd also use quotes around the `%backuppath%` in the `for /r` - just in case spaces creep in somewhere...

Comment: I ended up pulling all files into the parent directory then running this.
All my file names are unique so its ok they wont overwrite each other, and it turned out much faster than the recursive search. Still im toying around with it, very useful tool, thank you :)

`@ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "SDPath=MiSTer_SD"
set "backupPath=_ROOT"
for /R _ROOT %%i in (*.*) do move /y "%%i" "_ROOT\"
for /R "%SDPath%" %%G in (*.*) do (
    if %%~zG EQU 0 (
        MOVE "%backupPath%\%%~nxG" "%%G"
    )
)`

Comment: So it works with your addition, it errors out trying to move non existent files on the source end with similar names ( Trys to MOVE *.CHD from a folder it doesnt exist in) and takes forever to finish though. But does complete and doesnt everwrite any files or filenames.

Comment: With the original code, for each file find in the `sdpath` tree which is 0 bytes, you would scan the entire `root` tree, regardless of whether the file has already been moved. You *could* short-circuit that scan by moving the inner `for/r` to a subroutine and `goto :eof` after the `move`, or even simply `goto` the outer "for" loop after the move, which would restart the scan of `sdpath`.

Comment: With your revised strategy- note that the `/r` is redundant since files would only exist in `root`. Then consider the case where `sdpath` contains a 0-length file that does not exist in `root`. `backuppath`==`root`, so if `sdpath\imnotin.root` exists, you would attempt to move `root\imnotin.root`, which doesn't exist. You could gate this using an extra `if`... `if exist "%backupPath%\%%~nxG" move ...`

Comment: The handling of quotes by `for /R` is terrible (I consider that a design flaw), but you could perhaps use something like this instead: `for /F "delims=" %%g in ('dir /S /B /A:-D-H-S "%backupPath%\*%%~nxG"') do ( … )`